# cartodb make line twice on the same layer

Tags: sql, cartodb

I have a database with a_route and b_route. I want to make a line between all datapoints which have the same value for a_route and  another line for all datapoint which have the same value for b_route. So I want to have:

```
SELECT ST_MakeLine(the_geom) AS the_geom, a_route
FROM terminals
GROUP BY a_route
```

and

```
SELECT ST_MakeLine(the_geom) AS the_geom, b_route
FROM terminals
GROUP BY b_route
```

on the same layer

Comment: `UNION ALL` between them?

Comment: Great. That did it. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use can use `UNION ALL`:

```
SELECT ST_MakeLine(the_geom) AS the_geom, a_route
FROM terminals
GROUP BY a_route
UNION ALL 
SELECT ST_MakeLine(the_geom) AS the_geom, b_route
FROM terminals
GROUP BY b_route;
```